# Limit of sum with cube roots

Tags: limits

Do you have any hints for the following limit?

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^2}\left( {1 \over \sqrt[3]{1}} + {1 \over \sqrt[3]{2}} + {1 \over \sqrt[3]{3}} + \dots + {1 \over \sqrt[3]{n^2-1}} + {1 \over \sqrt[3]{n^2}} \right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hint:Let $a_k = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k}}\to 0$. Cesaro's theorem says: $S_n = \dfrac{a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_n}{n} \to 0$, thus the subsequence $S_{n^2} \to 0$ as well.

Answer (score 3):

One may use a Riemann sum, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
 \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \sqrt[3]{\frac{n^2}{k}}\to \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\:dx=\frac32
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k}}=\frac{1}{n^{2/3}} \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \sqrt[3]{\frac{n^2}{k}} \sim \frac{1}{n^{2/3}} \cdot \frac32 \to 0.
$$