# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{kn^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

In the very beginning, I'm going to refer to an already posted question quite similar to mine:

[Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{-3/2}(1+\sqrt{2}+\ldots+\sqrt{n})=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114065/limit-lim-n-to-infty-n-3-21-sqrt2-ldots-sqrtn-lim-n-to-infty)

And, to give an insight into what I've examined already:

[Limit of sum with cube roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004170/limit-of-sum-with-cube-roots).

> Compute:
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac1{\sqrt[3]{2}}+\ldots+\frac1{\sqrt[3]{n}}}{\sqrt[3]{n^2}}$$

My attempt:

As in the references, I also thought of applying *Stolz-Cesaro*, and got the following:

$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac1{\sqrt[3]{2}}+\ldots+\frac1{\sqrt[3]{n}}}{\sqrt[3]{n^2}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{k}}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt[3]{k}}}{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^2}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}}{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^2}}$

To avoid *L'Hospital*, I've done this:
$\begin{aligned}L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[3]{n+1}\left(\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^2}\right)}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1-\sqrt[3]{n^2(n+1)}}\\&=\frac1{\infty-\infty}\\&=\frac1{\infty}=0\end{aligned}$

I was wondering if there were another elegant method apart from *Riemann sum* or already used Stolz-Cesaro that I could use because this task appeared in *Analysis 1 exam.* Stolz-Cesaro is allowed and there was no constraint on any other methods, but I'm not familiar to Riemann sums at all.

To ask explicitly(for the sake of developing new ideas):

For example:
If I changed the order of the summands this way:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n-1}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}+1$$
would that be of any use in an algebraic manipulation that would lead me on the right track?
Final question:
Is my answer:$L=0$ correct?

Comment: umm. $L$ is not zero. typing more into elementary answer

Comment: $$  L =   \frac{3}{2} $$

Comment: noun form:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belles-lettres

Comment: Your mistake is that $\infty-\infty$ is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). You can't just equate it to $\infty$.

Comment: Always simplify your typing to avoid mistakes. Let's put $p=-1/3$ and then your expression under limit is $\dfrac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p$. This can be easily handled either via Cesaro-Stolz or using definite integrals as limit of sum to get limit $1/(p+1)$. Your previous limit linked here corresponds to $p=1/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is to rationalize the denominator. In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}}{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^2}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^4}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}\sqrt[3]{n^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^4}}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}((n+1)^2-n^2)}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^4}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}\sqrt[3]{n^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^4}}{2n\sqrt[3]{n+1}}\\
&=&\frac32.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you! All I was thinking of was not to do that having in mind the examples of the form with $1$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 7):

The limit of the ratio in your title is nonzero. Give me a few minutes to type up the following, based on your funtion $g(x) = x^{-1/3}$

if we have $g(x) > 0$ but $g'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; g(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  g(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  g(x) \; dx   $$

Here is a drawing I made, using the letter $f$ rather than $g$

[image]

Well, $g$ is integrable at the origin. Let's try $a=1.$ If that is not satisfactory we can just switch to $a=2$ by putting in some extra terms.

$$ \int_1^{n+1} \;  x^{-1/3} \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;   j^{-1/3} \; < \; \int_{0}^n \;   x^{-1/3} \; dx   $$

an antiderivative of $g$ is $G(x) = \frac{3}{2} x^{2/3}$

$$  \frac{3}{2} \left( (n+1)^{2/3} - 1 \right) \;  < \; \sum_{j=1}^n \;   j^{-1/3} \; < \;  \frac{3}{2}  n^{2/3}   $$

Good enough. Your denominator is simply $ n^{2/3}.$ We see that 
$$  L =   \frac{3}{2} $$

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Is this a form of the squeeze theorem? Since antiderivative is opposite to derivative, this is opposite to L'Hospital?

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya  I do not know a name for this. When I took calculus, this and the pictures were in every calculus book. If you can borrow a book written 45 years ago, you will find this.

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya: This is a standard technique. I learnt it while dealing with infinite series (integral test) . Using this one can prove that the limit of sequence $(\log n-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1/k))$ exists.

Comment: Also the comment about old books is correct. Modern books have lost the charm which classics had.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I learned integrals on my own last summer, we'll learn them formally in Analysis 2. I have some old books, but generally speaking, there are very few in my mother tongue and authors often refer to foreign books I can't borrow. Anyway, all the tasks are just being copied from those.

Answer (score 2):

How about a Riemann sum?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{kn^2}}
=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-1/3}
\to
\int_0^1 x^{-1/3}\;dx = \frac{3}{2}
$$
I guess this calculation is merely "suggestive", since the integral is improper.
(See my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/482107/442 for an example where Riemann sum fails on a convergent improper integral.)

To make this argument rigorous, do this:
Let $f(x) = x^{-1/3}$ on $(0,1)$.  Then $f \ge 0$ and $\int_0^1 f = 3/2$.  Now for a fixed $n$, let
$$
g_n(x) = \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-1/3}\quad \text{for } 
\frac{k-1}{n}<x \le\frac{k}{n},\quad k=1,2,\dots,n .
$$
Then $0 < g_n \le f$ and $g_n \to f$ pointwise, so by the dominated convergence theorem, we get $\int_0^1 g_n \to \int_0^1 f$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the example in the link!